# VBA Copying columns to matching date in excel calender

Tags: excel, plc, vba

I am attempting to learn some vba programming for excel, Long story short

I have a machine using an allen bradley plc, I have created a program in the plc to record hourly run statitistics, I have managed to get these to update live into an excel sheet, it uploads each hour for 24 hours. The machine runs on 3 shifts 6am to 2pm, 2pm to 10 pm, 10 pm to 6 am. In the factory we class each day as 6am to 6am.

I have written the following code, which copies the values from the plc and pastes them to the matching date, cell "c10" contains =today() then on sheet 2 it will paste the values to a calender under the matching date.

this is now working fine however i would like to change it so that under each date it contains 6am to 6 am values rather than 24 hours worth.

the issue i have is that cell c10 (todays date) will update after 12am and therefore the paste destination will change.

heres my code

```
Private Sub work_test()

 'set variables
    Dim Day As Date
    Dim rfound As Range
    Dim frow, fcol As Integer
    Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet

'set sheets
    Set sh1 = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("sheet2")

'sets day as current day, finds matching day in sheet2
     Day = sh1.Range("c10")
           Set rfound = sh2.Range("7:11").Find(Day, LookIn:=xlValues)

           If Not rfound Is Nothing Then

                frow = rfound.Row
                fcol = rfound.Column

                sh1.Range("c11:c34").Copy sh2.Cells(9, fcol)
            Else
                MsgBox "No match found"


           End If
'runs timer
     Call timer

End Sub

Sub timer()
'repeats cell update timer
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "work_test"
End Sub
```

Hope someone can help, not looking for a complete solution, just a bit of help in the correct direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two of many ways achieving what yo want:

1.- Replace formula in `C10` with this one:

```
   = TODAY() + IF( NOW() - TODAY() < TIME(6,0,0) , -1 , 0 )
```

Formula above validates the time and it less that 06:00:00 then rest one to the date. Thus anything between midnight and 06 AM will be taken as the day before

2.- In your code replace this line:

```
   Day = sh1.Range("c10")
```

with this:

```
   Day = Date + IIf(Time < TimeSerial(6, 0, 0), -1, 0)
```

Same as in point 1 above, only that since you are using VBA there is no need to have the date as a formula in the worksheet, the date of the machine can be obtain that directly in the VBA and proceed from there.